# Delete a value from NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I have a `NSMutableArray` named `_groupCategoryCurrentIds` whose data is in this format

```
(
        {
        id = 2;
        name = Fashion;
    },
        {
        id = 5;
        name = Leisure;
    },
        {
        id = 14;
        name = Clothing;
    },
        {
        id = 17;
        name = Sports;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = Fashion;
    },
        {
        id = 36;
        name = Men;
    },
        {
        id = 34;
        name = Woodland;
    },
        {
        id = 30;
        name = Accessories;
    },
        {
        id = 4;
        name = Entertainment;
    },
        {
        id = 40;
        name = Education;
    }
)
```

I'm trying to delete the object with id = 40 and this is how I do it

```
_groupCategoryCurrentIds = [[_groupCategoryCurrentIds filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT id IN %@", @"40"]] mutableCopy];
```

But this deletes the object with id =4 as well. Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id != %@", @"40"]
```

or

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id != %@", @40]
```

depending on whether the id is stored as a string or as a number.

Note that you can simplify your code to

```
[_groupCategoryCurrentIds filterUsingPredicate:...];
```

if `_groupCategoryCurrentIds` is a mutable array.

---

"IN" in a predicate is used for testing membership in an array or set, for example

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT id IN %@", @[@40, @50]]
```

to get all objects where the id is neither 40 nor 50.

Using "IN" with a *string* on the right-hand side is not documented
in the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1).
It seems to behave like "is a substring of", so that in your case

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT id IN %@", @"40"]
```

gives all objects where the id is not a substring of "40". That would explain your result.
But again, this is not documented behaviour.

Comment: +1 for great answer, For improve my knowledge if i want to get value which has **id** in between 40 to 50 then which pattern should be i need to use ?

Comment: @iPatel: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id >= %@ AND id <= %@", @40, @50]` or `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id BETWEEN %@", @[@40, @50]]` if the id is stored as a *number* (not as a *string*).